# Able to run Django server on PyCharm but not on command line?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I configured my virtual environment with virtualenvwrapper and I can run the server when I hit the run button on PyCharm. But when I type in manage.py runserver on my command line, I get this error message.

raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.

I'm using the PyCharm .env plug-ins to export my variables. And my .env file is sitting on the root of my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some tooling to read in that .env file outside PyCharm, then.

- https://pypi.org/project/envparse/ is a good all-around solution for just getting an `.env` file into `os.environ`.
- https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/ a similar one with better support for certain Django features such as configuring database URLs, etc.